# Is Intellij's "Find usages" limited by hierarchy depth?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an interface `SomeInterface` implemented by classes `A -> B -> C -> D` where `D` directly implements `SomeInterface` and `A` through `C` are an hierarchy of extensions.

I am trying to find usages of `SomeInterface` in a specific module via Intellij's Find Usages interface.
It seems to find `B, C, D, SomeInterface` but does not find A.

Is there a limit to depth? I am of course checking "Derived interfaces" and "Implementing classes" checkboxes in the find options dialog (see screenshot).

[image: Find options dialog]

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) sample. The files can be uploaded at https://uploads.jetbrains.com (do not forget to specify the UploadID here)

Comment: Sure, will find the time to do this at home.